# Bar plot with negative and positive values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, legend

I am using Matlab 2019a and I want to bar-plot positive and negative vectors, positive ones above and negative ones below the x-axis. The following code works fine except for...

a) the colors and legends. I want to have the same colors and corresponding legend entries for each the revenue and the opex vector.

b) I want to have those vectors that are mostly negative (in this case opex) closer to the x-axis when they are positive than those that are mostly positive (in this case revenue). I.e. always revenue above opex in the positive part of the plot.

I'd like to write it in an efficient way so that I can generalize it for more vectors. Thank you!

```
clc
clear
close all

revenue = ones(100,1);
opex = -1*ones(100,1);
opex(10:15,1) = 3;

revenueNeg = revenue;
revenueNeg(revenueNeg>0) = 0;
revenuePos = revenue;
revenuePos(revenuePos<0) = 0;
opexNeg = opex;
opexNeg(opexNeg>0) = 0;
opexPos = opex;
opexPos(opexPos<0) = 0;
yDataNeg = [revenueNeg, opexNeg];
yDataPos = [revenuePos, opexPos];
hold on;
bar(yDataNeg,'stack')
bar(yDataPos,'stack')
legend('Revenue','Opex');
hold off;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve (a) by storing a handle to the bar charts and setting the colors individually.

I'm interpreting (b) to mean that you want to sort the stack order according to the mean value of the series.

The code below can be expanded to more data series.  You'll want to supply a label for each element of `data`.  Colors come from the `parula` colormap.  (You could pick something else like `jet` if you prefer.)

[Edited in response to comments:]

```
data{1} = revenue;
data{2} = opex;
colors = parula(numel(data));
labels = {'Revenue','Opex'};
for i = 1:numel(data)
    dataNeg{i} = data{i};
    dataNeg{i}(data{i}>0) = 0;
    dataPos{i} = data{i};
    dataPos{i}(data{i}<0) = 0;
    mdata(i) = nnz(dataPos{i});  % was: mean(data{i});
end;
[~,posOrder] = sort(mdata,'ascend');
[~,negOrder] = sort(mdata,'descend');
yDataPos = [dataPos{posOrder}];
yDataNeg = [dataNeg{negOrder}];
hold on;
bNeg = bar(yDataNeg,'stack');
bPos = bar(yDataPos,'stack');
for i= 1:numel(data)
    set(bNeg(i),'FaceColor',colors(negOrder(i),:))
    set(bPos(i),'FaceColor',colors(posOrder(i),:))
end;
legend(labels{:});
hold off;
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good! However, I think you have to switch ascend and descend, right? Also, I'd like to sort by the relative number of times the vector is positive, not by the mean. And a problem with many vectors: I do not want to assign the colors manually, and I do not want any color repetitions either...

Comment: You can use one of the built-in colormaps to assign colors, or just use rand to choose them.  To sort by number of times positive, replace mean(data{i}) with nnz(dataPos{i}).

Comment: Can you suggest a new code, then I can accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have been travelling but I will test the new code tomorrow & accept.